# Apache Tomcat Listen Multiple Ports

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a Windows based Apache Tomcat installation.  The application is currently listening on port 8080.  I would like to create a redirect from the root of port 80 to the site being hosted in a sub directory on 8080.

Instead of entering the long URL to access the site (http://servername:8080/subdirectory/index.jsp) I would like to just enter (http://servername) and have this redirect to the sub-directory on port 8080.

I tired adding this to the server.xml without luck.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8443" />
```

I added this:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"/>
```

I also modified the index.jsp in the root directory to:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("server:8080/subdir/login.jsp"); %>
```

I still don't believe the site is listening on 80 and when visiting the root site "http://sitename:8080" I it's not redirecting.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am somewhat familiar with Apache but not with Tomcat.

Comment: What is the basis for your belief? Was there an error starting the port 80 connector? Does port 80 show up in `netstat`? And why should you get a redirect *from* port 8080 when your JSP redirects *to* port 80? Why are you using both ports at all? Why not just use port 80?

Comment: I have to keep port 8080 open as well.  This is a vendor requirement.  I am trying to make a user friendly URL which is why I need the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of most of this. Just change the existing single connector from port 8080 to port 80 and forget about port 8080 altogether. No redirection, no dual connectors, no nothing. Or if you must have both ports just use two Connectors. There's no apparent reason to use the redirect JSP to force the port change, just redirect to the sub page.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding the following to server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8080" />
```

I also added this to index.jsp within the root folder:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("http://servername:8080/subdir/page.jsp"); %>
```

Does this seem like an OK way to handle what I am trying to accomplish?  I don't mind if users see the redirected URL.

Comment: `redirectPort` should be 8443 in both cases. That's for SSL. Forcing it through 8080 first has no benefit. There's no real reason for the redirect JSP at all. Just let the server work on both ports.